# How to inherit when an instance created via parent's recursive @staticmethod in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, static-methods

```
class P:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  @staticmethod
  def from_static():
    return P()
  def parent():
    print("parent")


class C(P):
  def child():
    print("child")


c = C.from_static()

dir(c)

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'from_static', 'parent']
```

No child() method!

The static method redirects its own __init__ method, which is in the parent's class.
As a result, the instance of the 'c' method cannot possess the method child().

How can we define class 'c' with additional method child() if we want to create via the static method in the parent? I need not touch the 'p' class.

```
def f(x):
  return x*2, x**2

class P:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  @staticmethod
  def from_static(x):
    a, b = f(x)
    return P(a, b)
  def parent():
    print("parent")


class C(P):
  def child():
    print("child")


c = C.from_static()

dir(c)

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'from_static', 'parent']
```

The 2nd code is a specified code a little bit more.

Comment: You can add a new static method "from_static" to C which returns a C object.

Comment: When you call `C.from_static`, you get a `P` instance, not a `C` instance. That's what the `from_static` method that you've inherited is written to do! A better design for it would be a `classmethod` that creates an instance of the class it was called on, but that's not the design you've got.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I added the 2nd code. In this case, the 'from_static' should be the same form of all except for the 'return' line, e.g., return C(a,b) instead of return P(a,b).

Comment: @Blckknght 'A better design' you suggested is the `classmethod` in class `P`? So, shortly,  `@staticmethod` to `@classmethod` in `P` or `C`?

Comment: @NokiLee: Yes, making the method a `classmethod` would be much better. You'll also need to add another argument to the method, the class will be passed in as the first argument. Traditionally, that argument is named `cls`. You can change the `return P(a, b)` line to `return cls(a, b)` and it will then work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `C.from_static`, you get the same result as if you called `P.from_static`, an instance of the `P` class. That's because the method is designed to always return that result.

This is the downside of using static methods. They *always* do the same thing, regardless of what class you call them on. If you want the method to behave differently if it's called on a subclass, you probably don't want a `staticmethod`, but instead a `classmethod`.

When you call a `classmethod`, the method will get the class it was called on passed in as the first argument (traditionally named `cls`, though that's not obligatory). You can then call the class via that argument, rather than naming it yourself.

Try:

```
class P:
  @classmethod                  # change decorator
  def from_static(cls):         # add cls argument here
    return cls()                # call the class that was passed in, not always P
```

Comment: If we don't have this choice to fix `class P`, we have to manually add `from_static` in `C` as same as `P` except `return` line. Nice! Thank you!

Comment: Moreover, I realize that what situation forces to use `@classmethod`